# How to add empty folders when importing from SVN to Git under Windows?

Tags: windows, git, svn, administration, system-administration

I need to migrate multiple repositories from SVN to Git under Windows. Part of the repositories has empty folders, they are critical for projects and these folders cannot be deleted without breaking the project.

I tried the `git svn clone` command with the keys `--preserve-empty-dirs --placeholder-filename = .gitkeep` but this does not work at all.

As a result, the folder is not added to the commit history - this is a big problem because it is impossible to updade to the old version. After full migration the folder is also not added.

I tried to make a crutch to the mechanism, but I do not understand how to make it correctly:

This code creates zero-size files that Git does not process:
`for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do (fsutil file createnew %d/.gitkeep 0 && echo.>%%d/.gitkeep)`

This code creates files with a size of 2 bytes:
`for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do (echo.>%d/.gitkeep)`

In both cases, there is a problem with the fact that files are created in all folders, and not just empty ones. In addition, I lack an understanding of how to exclude the `.git` folder from processing.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

No way, but I wrote a crutch under Ubuntu 18.04, it works successfully in WSL:

```
echo The crutches for git svn clone --preserve-empty-dirs command, because it is not working properly.
```

find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" -exec echo blablabla>.gitkeep \;

git add --all